# Random Forest and missing values in numeric features

Tags: random-forest, missing-data

I'd like to use a random forest for predicting how long a person will stay a customer of our company.  One feature I'd like to use is the average age of the customer's kids.

The problem is some customers don't have kids so I can't compute an average.
Moreover I can't put 0 because this value means something else: the customer just had his first kid.

**How could I handle these missing values in random Forest?**

Does it make sense to substitute with a impossible value like -1? If yes is it even better to use a big negative values like - 500?

Comment: Put 0 and make a second feature that is a binary indicator for whether or not the customer has kids. Feature scaling is irrelevant in RF since it just looks for cutpoints, not at the range of values.

Comment: As feature scaling is indeed irrelevant, could you not code the missing values with -1 and leave the zeros as is?

Answer (score -1):

In your case I would start with some feature engineering. As mentioned by @user777, start with creating a new variable that indicates whether or not a customer has kids. Then I would look into more details, maybe an indicator with the number of kids. If you have the age of the kids, look into creating age range buckets, or check if a polynomial of age has any relevance.